# How to let `docker run --gpus all` gracefully fall back to CPU if GPU is not present?

Tags: docker, gpu

I need to run a docker image on two machines: one with GPU and the other without GPU. In order to use GPU, I currently pass the `--gpus all` option to `docker run` as follows (otherwise, GPU is not detected by `pytorch` code inside the container):

```
docker run -dt -P --name "ch4-dev" --label "..." -v ".../debugpy:/debugpy:ro,z" --entrypoint "python3" --gpus all "ch4:latest"
```

The above `docker run` command is assembled by VS Code python extension. It runs correctly on the machine with the GPU, and `torch.cuda.is_available()` returns True.

However, on the machine without GPU, the same project generates the following error:

> docker: Error response from daemon: could not select device driver ""
> with capabilities: [[gpu]]. The terminal process failed to launch
> (exit code: 125).

The Question:

*Is there a more flexible option than `--gpu=all` that will detect/use a GPU if exists, and otherwise fall back to using CPU gracefully without an error?*

Comment: It's will be extremely helpfull, I have the same problem to make vscode devcontainer work with both cpu only and gpu

Comment: It's maybe the ugliest things but I don't have anything better. You can interplotate the number of gpus and echo the right things in consequence (nothing if no gpu and --gpus --all else): [ $(ls -la /dev | grep nvidia | wc -l) "==" "0"  ] && echo "" || echo "--gpus all"

Comment: @JulienBlanchon sorry to resurrect this thread, but were you able to use interpolation within devcontainer.json?

Comment: Hey @Alleo, No I finally make a two seperated .devcontainer file: one for CPU and one for GPU

Comment: @JulienBlanchon
Try this in devcontainer.json. No need to use two files.
 "hostRequirements": {
  "gpu": "optional"
 },

Answer (score 0):

using `nvidia-docker` command directly instead of the `docker`.